# pointing subclass object by superclass reference variable

Tags: java, inheritance

when we can point the object of subclass with superclass reference variable then why can't we access a subclass method with that reference variable of superclass..

for eg.
following code gives error..

```
    class Parent
    {    
        int a;
    }

    class Child extends Parent
    {
        void func()       
        {
            System.out.println("abc");
        }

  public static void main(String s[])      
  { 
       Parent a=new Child();
            a.func();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code is perfectly fine, and should print `abc`. What error does it show you?

Answer (score 3):

Let me ask you a question, did you ever see son have a child and this child is really his father?!! Sounds crazy ha!

So, `class Parent extends Child` is not a compile error, but compare it to real live, is it possible?

So, your code is fine but change it to:

```
class Parent
{    
    void func()
    {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Parent a=new Child();
        a.func();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct (and much easier to read). However, it should really be `Parent a = new Child();`

Comment: @supersam654: I forgot to change this, thanks for the hint

Comment: sorry bro but now i have corrected it.i have edited my code so now take a look at it..

Comment: It's better now, and please accept an answer, read this link [**StackOverFlow.com/about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a Parent class to subclass. The reason is subclass might have methods or properties that do not exist in Parent and hence you won't be able to call child class methods.

Comment: The OPs classes are fine, they're just named backwards.

Comment: A parent class reference can be made pointed to a sub class object, but then this parent class reference can use the dot operator to access the members of the parent class and only the overriden member functions from the sub class. To access other member functions inside the sub class that are not overridden but newly defined, you need to create a sub class reference. This is called Dynamic Binding

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that you don't have any constructors, but I assume that you didn't paste your entire code.

Comment: why is that a problem?

Comment: Some people consider it a bad practice to omit a default constructor. While there are valid arguments to support this, it is an opinion and not fit for an answer on SO.